# Recording the sound of my Mac

Tags: mac, audio, recording

Is there a way to capture the currently playing "sounds" ?

For instance, If I want to copy (to an audio-file) the noise I make while playing a flash game, is there a way to record what is currently to be heard in my headset ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rogue Amoeba's [Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/) can do this for you and much more.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it for free you can download Audacity and Soundflower (if you have a mac) and record the sound straight off your sound card.

Audacity: http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/

Soundflowerbed: http://cycling74.com/downloads/

Tutorial: [http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/User:BillWharrie/Using_Soundflower_to_record_streaming_audio](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/User%3aBillWharrie/Using_Soundflower_to_record_streaming_audio)

You mentioned you're using a mac, but for people who run windows, there is likely another program you can substitute for Soundflower to accomplish the same thing, although I have not looked into it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, also from Rogue Amoeba, is [Piezo](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/piezo/) which is about 50% the cost of Audio Hijack Pro. So, depending on how complex your needs are, there are two really great options.

Answer (score 0):

Soundflower has been my optimal software for audio routing. You can grab it here: http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/. Please note that this is only available for Mac. If you own a Windows computer, (or GNU/Linux, Solaris, or FreeBSD, or even Mac as well, in addition to any POSIX-conformant platforms), try JACK at http://jackaudio.org. Both of these are free, so try them out.

Answer (score 0):

[TapeDeck](http://tapedeckapp.com) is another such app to the list. It literally has a nice looking interface featuring a classic tape recorder, with a "drawer of tapes" on the side, which is a stack of the recordings that you've made with it before. The data there displays title, time or recording, and the duration.
To record, choose the setting "Record using system audio recorder", and it should record the sound straight from your sound card, i.e. whatever comes out of your headphones/speakers. Free evaluation version is available, and if you find it useful for something that you need to do a lot, the full version is worth it. For me, it's been stable and I like the simplicity of the layout, easy little thing that doesn't take too much area on the screen.